# complex survey in python

Tags: python, survey, survey-weights, lifelines

I have been using the excellent R `survey` package for survival analysis of complex survey data. I have the necessity to migrate to python, and have found that the Python package `lifelines` gives the possibility to define sampling weights and clusters in the  `CoxPHFitter`. For example, reusing pieces of codes from their [tutorial](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Survival%20Regression.html), I would use:

```
import pandas as pd
from lifelines import CoxPHFitter

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'T': [5, 3, 9, 8, 7, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 7],
    'E': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    'weights': [1.1, 0.5, 2.0, 1.6, 1.2, 4.3, 1.4, 4.5, 3.0, 3.2, 0.4, 6.2],
    'month':  [1, 3, 9, 8, 7, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 7],
    'age':    [4, 3, 9, 8, 7, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 7],
    'id':     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
})

cph = CoxPHFitter()
cph.fit(df, 'T', 'E', weights_col='weights', cluster_col='id', robust=True)
cph.print_summary()
```

to have a Cox Proportional Hazard model. Would this be equivalent of using  `svycoxph`?

N.B: I'd add the tag `lifelines` but it does not exists and I do not have the minimum reputation (300) to create it. I'd appreciate if anybody would edit this question adding that tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Cam.Davidson.Pilon says, there are some differences. But not a lot.

There's one big difference: `svycoxph` can account for stratified sampling, which `coxph` and (apparently) `lifelines` cannot.  This can be important if you have good stratification, but ignoring stratification is conservative.

Another difference is that `svycoxph` can distinguish between sampling with and without replacement. That's probably not a big issue, since with a regression model you usually want inference about the data generating process rather than the finite population.

There will also be very minor differences of the $n/(n-1)$ sort, where the formulas aren't identical between clustered/longitudinal data analysis and survey sampling.

So, stratification is the potentially important issue.  If you're analysing data from NHANES, stratification could matter.  Most of the time it won't -- except that you'll get different answers from what survey statisticians get and you might have to explain why.

Answer (score 4):

*lifelines'* author here.

I am not familiar with the inner workings of svycoxph, so I can't comment authoritatively on the similarities of it and `CoxPHFitter`. Looking at its [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survey/versions/4.0/topics/svycoxph) page, there are some difference that *lifelines* doesn't handle, for example

> accounts for the reduction in variance from stratified sampling and the increase in variance from having only a small number of clusters

I would treat *lifelines'* `CoxPHFitter` as most similar to `coxph` in the `survival` library, and compare what differences `coxph` has from `svycoxph`. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and thanks for `lifelines`, great tool too. I will try the comparison you suggest. Do I interpret the documentation correctly in my question, beyond the variance issue? That is, would the point estimate be correct if in the `CoxPHFitter` I use the `id` to model the unique clusters and the `weights_col` are the sample weights?

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. To answer your question: I believe so, yes.